# Avoiding includeJsFile, includeJS from caching

Tags: cache, craft2, includejs

In my template, I have an `includeJSFile` that loads properly on the first load, but disappears on subsequent loads.

The `includeJSFile` is outside the caching tags, so I'm not sure why this is still happening. There's no caching in my `layout.twig` as well.

I also have a variable set in my template that I'm calling in via the `includeJS` tag (placed outside of the cache tags), and that seems to be having the same issue as well. Any idea to resolve this? Here's the setup.

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% block content %}
    {% cache globally using key craft.request.path %}

    {% set entries = craft.entries({
        section: 'MY-SECTION',
        with: [
        'MY-ASSET-FIELD'
        ]
    }) %}

    -- MY ENTRY LOOP -- 

{% endcache %}

{% includeJsFile 'MY-JS.js' %}

{% set MY-JS-VARIABLE %}

    -- MY JS CONTENT THAT LOOPS THROUGH SECTION ENTRIES TO INSTANTIATE MY JS OBJECTS --

{% endset %}

{% includeJs MY-JS-CONTENT %}
{% endblock %}
```